# Is goodness-of-fit a reasonable way to test the usefulness of correlated precitors

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, goodness-of-fit

Under a hypothesis testing framework, I would like to model $Y \sim X_1 + X_2 + Z$ where `X_1` and `X_2` are two related, likely correlated measures of the same construct.

Is it reasonable to use ANOVA to test the model fit as a way to test whether this construct has a relationship with `Y`?

Here's some R pseudocode outlining what I'm proposing:

```r
fit_1 = lm(y ~ z, data = df)
fit_2 = lm(y ~ x1 + y1 + z, data = df)

anova(fit_1, fit_2)
```

Answer (score 3):

This indeed makes sense, since $Y \sim Z$ is nested within $Y \sim X_1 + X_2 + Z$ and that you fit both models on `df`. Alternatively, you could also:

- Perform cross validation to compare the ability of both models to generalize to held-out data
- Use model selection criteria, such as the AIC or the BIC
- Also compare these models to $Y \sim X_1  + Z$ and $Y \sim  X_2 + Z$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use an F test for the multiple regression R/R-squared and for the difference (change) in R-squared when adding additional predictors to the model (assuming Y is a continuous variable so linear regression makes sense).

You wrote that X1 and X1 are supposed to represent a common construct. As a result, X1 and X2 may be strongly correlated. This may result in effects of collinearity in the regression model  (e.g., suppression, high standard errors). Have you considered using structural equation modeling where X1 and X2 could be used as indicators of a common factor and you could regress Y on the common factor in addition to Z (instead of including both X1 and X2 in the same regression model)?